# Css h1 matching div width

Tags: html, css

I have the following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1 style="margin-bottom: 0;">Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div style="background-color: red; height: 100px; width: 250px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically I would like to give my h1 a `width` that the text inside it should occupy no matter if I add or remove a word (adapting the `font-size` and `the letter-spacing` according to it). I could change my "Hello Plunker" and the last letter should still finish where the div below finishes.

I can use some js if needed but not Jquery

Comment: wrap that content inside a parent `div` and set it that `fixed width`. Then you can manage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ugly answer, but it might just do the trick if you plan on sticking to CSS. Hopefully someone will be able to point out a better way, however.

This idea relies on the fact that `text-align: justify` will spread out all lines of text but the last one (or the only one in case of just one line). Therefore, we're adding some useless text just to make sure there are at least two lines of text. Then, we try to hide the second line. I'm sure this could be improved upon:

```css
h1 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 1.4em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
  text-align: justify;
}

h1 span {
  visibility: hidden;
  display:inline-block;
  line-height: 0px;
}

div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello Plunker<span>make sure there are two lines, pretty please?</span></h1>
<div></div>
```

You can edit the [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/su36jv42/2/). To be honest, I guess it would be better to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use JS, then http://fittextjs.com/ is worth a look. I don't think is achievable using CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

Just an Idea of using `transform:scale(jQueryCalc)` - to make content fit its parents innerWidth.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".fit").each(function() {
    $(this).css("transform", "scale(" + ($(this).parent().innerWidth() / $(this).width()) + ")");
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: red;
  height: 70px;
  width: 250px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.fit{
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  float: left;
  transform-origin: left top;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="fit">Hello Plunker!</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span class="fit">Well this should work</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span class="fit">Well this should work; Well this should work</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span class="fit">Well this should work; Well this should work; Well this should work; Well this should work</span>
</div>
```